# Para que serve o cabeçalho "P3P"?

Tags: http, http-headers

Recentemente encontrei um cabeçalho com nome de `P3P`, nunca tinha visto isso antes e não sei qual é o real impacto no uso desse cabeçalho.

Eu encontrei algumas informações, [como essa enorme documentação](https://www.w3.org/TR/P3P/), [algumas informações basicas](https://www.w3.org/P3P/introduction.html) e [que o Facebook abandonou esse recurso](https://www.facebook.com/help/327993273962160/).

---

Minha questão é:

1. Qual é o real uso do P3P? Ele teria o intuito de informar ao usuário quais dados seriam coletados?
2. O P3P ainda é usado? Os navegadores ainda suportam esse cabeçalho ou já é considerado obsoleto?
3. Existe algum substituto ou equivalente do P3P?

Comment: Por eu nunca ter visto ele antes e pela data dos materiais, acredito fortemente que está, de fato, obsoleto.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, também acredito que esteja. Pelo que conseguir achar ele já "nasceu morto", apenas o IE suportava isso, o Mozilla suportou por alguns anos. Ele parece ser usado apenas para permitir uso de cookies (e iframes?!) em versões muito antigas do IE, pelo que entendi. O que é mais estranho é até agora não ter surgido uma "alternativa", existe o DNT, mas não parece cumprir o mesmo propósito. :\